# How to add new rows but keep existing data same?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which updates every few hours i.e. new rows are added and data for existing rows may also change.

I am looking for an output where the new rows are added but the existing data does not get over-written with the changes but changes are show in a new column

I am using big query so some standard functions may not work. does this require loops?

*Base table at T=0*

```
id food    
1 cake    
2 pepsi    
3 peanut
4 chicken
```

*Base table at T=1 (a new row has been added i.e. id 5)*

```
id  food    
1   cake    
2   pepsi    
3   peanut    
4   chicken    
5   watermelon
```

**Output at T=1**

```
id  food         change
1   cake         NULL    
2   pepsi        NULL    
3   peanut       NULL
4   chicken      NULL    
5   watermelon   NULL
```

---

*Base table at T=2 (a new row has been added i.e. id-6 and food names for id-3 and id-5 have been changed)*

```
id  food    
1   cake    
2   pepsi    
3   sushi    
4   chicken    
5   wrap    
6   Cherry
```

**Output at T=2**

```
id  food        change    
1   cake        NULL    
2   pepsi       NULL    
3   peanut      sushi    
4   chicken     NULL    
5   watermelon  wrap    
6   Cherry      NULL
```

Comment: Try creating some triggers or some back up table that takes back up of current data before new data gets inserted or current data gets changed

Comment: if A changed to B and after a few hour B changed to C, How you wants to keep ref of all values?

Comment: Hi, If A changes to B and B changes to C then I need C! Also please note that I using big query so a lot of standard SQL Server functions don't work

Comment: @userag123 . . . I added the BigQuery tag based on your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `update` to change the value, then there is nothing you can do.  You have changed the data and you don't have a record of earlier data.

If you are inserting the data with a timestamp, then you can construct a query.  Your data would look like:

```
id  food      timestamp  
1   cake           0    
2   pepsi          0  
3   peanut         0
4   chicken        0
1   cake           1   
2   pepsi          1    
3   peanut         1
4   chicken        1
5   watermelon     1
```

Then a typical method to get the current values might be:

```
select id, food, prev_food
from (select t.id, t.food,
             lag(t.food) over (partition by t.id order by t.timestamp) as prev_food,
             dense_rank() over (order by t.timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

In BigQuery, this can actually be simplified to:

```
select id,
       array_agg(food order by timestamp desc limit 1)[safe_ordinal(1)],
       array_agg(food order by timestamp desc limit 2)[safe_ordinal(2)]
from t
group by id;
```

This does, however, assume that `id` do not disappear.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. The base table does not have a timestamp column so how do I create one for every iteration of the table?

Comment: @userag123 . . . Your code is probably doing updates then.  Read the first paragraph.  You don't have the historical data so you cannot retrieve it in a query.  You need to fix our data processing.

Comment: sorry not able to understand. i don't have any code at the moment as i did not know how to approach this. Is there some loop concept? like at T=0, I create table1 and append new rows from base table after a lookup to create table2. Then table1 itself updates and becomes same as table 2 and so on

Comment: @userag123 . . . When you load data into BigQuery, you can include the timestamp of the load.  This would actually be a best practice, if you want to shard or partition the data.

Answer (score 0):

With the above input/output and under the assumption that the value can changes only once, in postgreSQL we could do something like this.

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, food)
VALUES
   (
      3,
      'Sushi'
   ) 
ON CONFLICT (id) 
DO
      UPDATE
     SET change = excluded.food;
```

We could use similar methodology in MySQL but the syntax would be different.

Comment: Thanks sir - i am looking for a more generic solution, this one is only for 1 record. also i am using big query so a lot of standard fuctions don't work!